# Installing node.js on Debian 6.0

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, installation

So well, I have a vserver with Debian 6.0.

Now I would like to install Node.js, but none of the tutorials on the web seem to work.
I have tried all of the results google gives me when I enter "install node.js on linux"
I mostly failed because I had no idea how to install the dependencies (I'm new to linux btw)

How to install node.js on a Debian system that was just setup (so no programs already installed on it and such)?

Comment: You don't need to install the current node.js package or build manually anymore. [Just use NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although, as ArjunShankar says, you should normally use a pre-built package. Node.js is rather too fast moving for Debian packages to keep up. I would strongly recommend that you do your own installs until such a time as Node settles down. For example, there was an unexpected update recently that fixes an important security loophole - you do not want to be dependent on a package that is for an out-of-date version of Debian when things need to move fast.

Instead, you should install from source.

You can download the source archive direct unpack it into a temporary folder and follow the instructions on the [Node Github page](https://github.com/joyent/node). Alternatively, if you are confident with GIT, you can use that to grab the source - again to a temporary folder & follow the installation instructions.

There are a number of software dependencies for compiling so you need to make sure that you have them first - they should all be in the Debian apt packages. See http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2011/04/26/installing-nodejs-couchdb-and-npm-on-debian-the-easy-way/ or http://sekati.com/etc/install-nodejs-on-debian-squeeze for further information.

It will take a few minutes to do the compile so be patient.

Once you've done it once, upgrades are also easy - just repeat the download/compile process.

Node.js installations now include the npm tool so installing libraries and other code is extremely simple.

Answer (score 101):

If anyone else needs step-by-step instructions, I used the following steps from [Install Node.js on Debian Squeeze](http://sekati.com/etc/install-nodejs-on-debian-squeeze) and it installed with no problems:

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev`
2. `git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git`
3. `cd node`
4. `git checkout v5.0.0` (or the version you want to build)
5. `./configure`
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`
8. `node -v`
9. `npm -v`

I didn't have to install any additional sources into apt to get it to build.

Comment: perfect answer. it is fine for Ubuntu too.

Comment: This worked for me on LMDE UP6 after the instructions from github faild.

Comment: Worked like a charm with Debian 7 x86 on a VM.

Comment: Worked on Debian 8 x86 as well.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu vivid on Orange PI nice

Answer (score 12):

As others have mentioned, node.js has quite a rapid release cycle, and the official Debian packages lag somewhat. I have a need to keep a group of Debian servers up-to-date with node.js, so I've been using this:

https://github.com/mark-webster/node-debian

Which allows you to build .deb files for arbitrary versions of node.js, so you can install / upgrade / uninstall it easily. It's a bit quick and dirty, but at least it's something until the official Debian packages arrive.

For an insight into the complications facing Debian package maintainers regarding node.js, see this thread:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/W_6avRSG_a8/xeQxLGuHQ5YJ

Comment: This seems to be a very clean and up-to-date solution for when you need a newer node and/or don't want to include debian repo's for a newer release than you have (node is in Sid/testing right now)

Comment: Indeed, I had too many Debian boxes mixing stable / testing / unstable packages, which was a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add this:

http://ypcs.fi/howto/2012/10/09/nodejs-debian/

I successfully used this for wheezy, however I only got v0.6.19 and it is atm on 0.8.2.

Comment: The link above is not working anymore. no explanation of what steps you followed to make nodejs work!

Comment: @Digitalsite Well, this answer is highly outdated. Today I would just advice to use the prebuilt binaries and extract the compressed archive to /usr/local or something, fastest and easiest way. You can even find prebuilt binaries for armhf platforms, like raspberry pi and similar. Node.js has very few dependencies so it's not a huge problem handling this outside of apt.

Answer (score 2):

I added my own node.js / debian package builder here:

https://github.com/aw/nodejs-debian

It uses the official node.js git repo to pull down the exact version you want to build, and creates an easy to distribute .deb package.